# Selectively pushing elements from array A to array C which are not present in array B

Tags: arrays, perl, array-filter

I am trying to produce an array called @names which contains the names of people who are present in allnames.txt but not in somenames.txt.  My code is as follows:

```
if(open(SKIPLIST, "somenames.txt")) {       
    @some = <SKIPLIST>;
}
close(SKIPLIST);

if(open(TESTLIST, "allnames.txt")) {        
    @all = <TESTLIST>;
}
close(TESTLIST);

foreach $name (@all) {
    $name =~ s/[\n\r]//mg;
    if (grep {$_ eq $name} @some) {
        #Do nothing
    }
    else {
        push(@names, $name);
    }
}

print "Leftover: @names";
```

Contents of allnames.txt:

```
adam
jake
john
troy
```

Contents of somenames.txt:

```
adam
john
```

Actual output:

```
Leftover: adam jake troy
```

Expected output:

```
Leftover: jake troy
```

Can anyone explain why 'adam' is still getting pushed?

Answer (score 2):

`"adam"` is included in the results because your `@some` array only contains `"adam\n"`.  To fix it, just do

```
chomp @some, @all;
```

or, if you want to be paranoid about DOS line breaks,

```
s/[\r\n]+$// for @some, @all;
```

before your main loop.  Then you also won't need the line

```
$name =~ s/[\n\r]//mg;
```

inside the loop.

---

Also, if you want your code to be fast, you should really use a hash instead of the `@some` array, like this:

```
my %some;
if (open SKIPLIST, "somenames.txt") {       
    while (my $name = <SKIPLIST>) {
        chomp $name;
        undef $some{$name};  # create the key $name in the hash %some
    }
    close SKIPLIST;
}

my @names;
if (open TESTLIST, "allnames.txt") {        
    while (my $name = <TESTLIST>) {
        chomp $name;
        push @names, $name unless exists $some{$name};
    }
    close TESTLIST;
}

print "Leftover: @names\n";
```

Comment: To really nitpick, \n is the current OS's line separator, you want to look for \015 and \012 to handle Unix and DOS line separators regardless of what OS the program is running on.

Comment: @daxelrod: True, although that will only make a difference on some rather unusual platforms.  (I believe perhaps the least obscure system where `"\n" ne "\x0A"` is Mac OS Classic, although the regexp I gave works on that platform too.)  Anyway, I edited my answer but then changed it back: `s/[\n\r]+$//` is at least guaranteed to correctly remove native line endings on any platform, and shouldn't damage any printable characters.  (At least, I'd be _very_ surprised if `"\r"` mapped to a printable character anywhere.)

Comment: On Windows (in, say, Strawberry Perl), in text mode, I believe that `\n\r` will not match a Unix line separator. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines for a handy table. That said, I agree with your reasoning to leave it as `\n\r`, since that seems to be closest to what the asker already had. :)

Comment: `\n\r` will indeed not match a Unix line feed (on any platform), but `[\n\r]` will. :)

Comment: @daxelrod, @Ilmari Karonen, On all supported platforms, `\n` is LF and `\r` is CR, and `$/` is initialised to LF. With Windows's default perlio layers,  CRLF is automatically translated to LF on read and vice-versa on write. If you want to be flexible, just use `s/\s+\z//;`. It'll even get rid of inconvenient trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is some of your elements have trailing and/or leading whitespace (\n or \r) and some don't.  The best way to fix it is to clean them right after reading the file:

```
if(open(SKIPLIST, "somenames.txt")) {       
    @some = <SKIPLIST>;
    foreach (@some) { $_ =~ s/[\n\r]//mg; }
}
close(SKIPLIST);

if(open(TESTLIST, "allnames.txt")) {        
    @all = <TESTLIST>;
    foreach (@all) { $_ =~ s/[\n\r]//mg; }
}
close(TESTLIST);

foreach $name (@all) {
    if (grep {$_ eq $name} @some) {
        #Do nothing
    }
    else {
        push(@names, $name);
    }
}

print "Leftover: @names";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're removing the newlines from what you get from `TESTLIST`, but not from what you get from `SKIPLIST`.

I'd use a hash instead of `grep` for quick lookups, so my code would more like

```
my %some;
while (<SKIPLIST>) {
   s/\s+\z//;
   ++$some{$_};
}

my @names;    
while (<TESTLIST>) {
   s/\s+\z//;
   push @names, $_ if !$some{$_};
}
```

Or if you want something in a functional programming style,

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( apply );
my %some = map { $_ => 1 } apply { s/\s+\z//; } <SKIPLIST>;
my @names = grep !$some{$_}, apply { s/\s+\z//; } <TESTLIST>;
```

If you have duplicate names and you want to get duplicate names, change `!$some{$_}` to `!$some{$_}++` (in either snippet).

Comment: @TLP, Be the judge yourself: `apply { s/\s+\z//; }` vs `map { my $_ = $_; s/\s+\z//; $_ }`

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the input list will be discarded anyway. It seems to be extra trouble for no reason.

Comment: There is also the not-so-pretty `grep { s|\s*\z|| }` option for the module-paranoid...

Comment: @TLP, `map { s/\s+\z//; }` doesn't work, so extra trouble is necessary. The remaining question is whether to do it safely or not. What do you have against `apply`?

Comment: @Zaid, I don't cater to the "module-paranoid". Essential parts of Perl programming aren't in the `perl` distribution.

Comment: @ikegami `map { s/\s+\z//; $_ }` does work, though. I have nothing against apply. I am seeing no difference between using apply and map, except that apply does not alter the input list, so I was curious as to your reasons for choosing it over map. Hence my initial question.

Comment: @TLP, Don't you think I know? That's the point. You have to do extra work with map whether you protect the list or not, and if you don't protect the list, it's a risky, bad habit. Simpler and safer wins every time in my book.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write loops to iterate over the two sets of names. Use of `map` and a hash slice makes it much clearer what is going on.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh;

open $fh, '<', 'somenames.txt' or die $!;
chomp(my @some = <$fh>);

open $fh, '<', 'allnames.txt' or die $!;
chomp(my @all = <$fh>);

my %diff = map(($_ => 1), @all);
delete @diff{@some};

print join(' ', "Leftover:", keys %diff), "\n";
```